# qt code compiled on local computer give error while run on another computer

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I write a code in qt creator under Ubuntu (vmware one). the code compiled and run on my computer correctly. But when I try to compile the code on university supercomputer it give the following error:

```
./Test02_Qt: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It should be added that I tried to compile my code on the supercomputer using make command and I got the following error :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file; no such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile] Error 127
```

please help me on this issue.

Regards

Comment: you need to install Qt libraries on the other computers. Something like `qtbase5-dev`

Comment: Yes. I check the university supercomputer and qt 5.4.2 is installed already

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your software on the target machine to ensure that all libraries match. Compiling against library version A on computer 1 and then running against version B on computer 2 might outright fail or have side-effects.

Have a look at this:

> error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6

This is a common error if operating system versions do not match (most probably, the supercomputer has an older version of `libstdc++` installed).

To understand why your compilation on the target machine does not work, we need more information on your build setup. Are you using a plain Makefile? Autotools?  QMake? CMake? Normally your build system should not dictate a specific version of `libstdc++` and it might be you have to re-initialize it or edit the Makefile.

Comment: I just eddited the addres path in the Makefile (convert its adddres from my computer addresses to supercomputer addreses) and then went to the directory of code in the supercomputer and and type make and run this command.

Comment: Did you write the Makefile yourself?

Comment: No it was created by Qt. I just modify some addreses from my computer path to supercomputer addreses.

Comment: Most probably you have a QMake project then and should call qmake on the target machine to re-generate the Makefile. Or it is Cmake. Do you have a CMakefiles.txt or a *.pro file? See the documentation on QMake or CMake then and you are set.

Comment: first of all thank you. I don't have CMakefiles.txt but i have .pro file and when i tried to call qmak by typing: qmake -o Makefile Test02_Qt.pro I got the following error : -bash: qmake: command not found.

Comment: aslo when I add qmake addres to it and type my command as follow: "/share/apps/qt/Qt5.4.2/5.4/gcc/bin/qmake -o Makefile Test02_Qt" I got the libstdc++.so.6 error which mentioned above.

Comment: I suggest to ask the administrators of your supercomputer about their Qt installation then, as it seems to be broken.

Comment: Thanks you are right. Is it possible this libraries (libstdc++.so.6) is not installed on the supercomputer? the administrator say that the difference between gcc versions leads to this error.

Comment: As I said in my answer, most probably the supercomputer has an older version installed. Which is, yes, based on the GCC version. What you have to ask the administrator is why the Qt installation does not match the system.

Comment: Thanks. Administrator say that the reason come back to gcc which is (x64) for supercomputer and (x32) for my ubuntu which installed on virtual machine. It is not possible for me to install x64 ubuntu on my virtual machine due to some hardware restrictions.